# Databinding TypeConverter error in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-databinding, companion-object

I'm using TypeConverter in some of my data-bindings. The issue is that it requires static functions and when I convert it into Kotlin it goes into the companion object and data-binding processor can't track the change.

I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required DataBindingComponent is null
>   in class ListMainBinding. A BindingAdapter in
>   com.noisyninja.androidlistpoc.model.DataConverter.Companion is not
>   static and requires an object to use, retrieved from the
>   DataBindingComponent. If you don't use an inflation method taking a
>   DataBindingComponent, use DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent or make
>   all BindingAdapter methods static.
>       at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.ensureBindingComponentIsNotNull(ViewDataBinding.java:554)

How do I make it recognise static @TypeConverter annotated methods in companion object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add @jvmStatic annotation above the Binding Adapter method, something like this:

```
@BindingAdapter(value = "visiblity")
@JvmStatic
fun showHide(view : View, show : Boolean){
    view.visibility = when {
        show -> View.VISIBLE
        else -> View.GONE
    }
}
```